# Using TwitterOauth to get user timeline, always returns "page not found", code 34

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to get the user timeline for my twitter timeline, and it keeps giving me the return "page not found".  The code is below:

```
require_once("twitteroauth/autoload.php");
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($this->consumer_key, $this->consumer_secret, $this->oauth_access_token, $this->oauth_access_token_secret);
$data = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$this->username."&count=".$this->limit); 
return $data;
```

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it, and initially ran into the same issue.  Reading [This Documentation](https://twitteroauth.com/), it appears that there is a different format for making API requests with the TwitterOAuth library.

The example in this post was helpful as well: [How to get the 3,200 tweets (Twitter API 1.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428091/how-to-get-the-3-200-tweets-twitter-api-1-1)

Try this, it worked for me:

```
require_once("twitteroauth/autoload.php");
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($this->consumer_key, $this->consumer_secret, $this->oauth_access_token, $this->oauth_access_token_secret);


$data = $connection->get("statuses/user_timeline", array('count' => $this->limit, 'exclude_replies' => true, 'screen_name' => $this->username));

return $data;
```